# Are HTML5 Web Workers threads or processes?

Tags: javascript, html, concurrency, parallel-processing, web-worker

From the Mozilla documentation:

> Web Workers is a simple means for web content to run scripts in
>   background threads.

Considering Javascript is single-threaded, are web workers separate *threads* or *processes*? Is there shared memory that classifies them as threads?

Comment: You could share memory between workers and main thread with SharedArrayBuffer but due to spectre vulnerability it is disabled in most browsers (it can be used as a high-resolution timer)

Comment: For some OSes it does not matter. For Linux specifically threads and processes are the same thing. On Linux you can start with a thread, cut off connections to your parent thread and do some other configurations and end with a process. You can also start with a process, join a process group and do some other configurations and end with a thread. Linux implement threads and processes in the same data structure

Answer (score 5):

They run in background [threads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers), but the API completely abstracts from the implementation, so you may come across a browser that just schedules them to run on the same thread as other events like Node does. Processes are too heavyweight to run background tasks.

Comment: The spec just calls them ["separate execution environments"](https://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#processing-model) and just like you said, it doesn't mandate the use of threads or processes. The browser can use any of the 2 models.

Answer (score 1):

> Considering Javascript is single-threaded

JavaScript is not single-threaded.

The main part of a JavaScript program runs on an event loop.

Long-running processes (XMLHttpRequest being the classic example) are almost always farmed out to stuff that runs outside the event loop (often on different threads).

Web Workers are just a means to write JavaScript that runs outside the main event loop.

> are web workers separate threads or processes? Is there shared memory that classifies them as threads?

That's an implementation detail of the particular JS engine.

Comment: But wait. Isn't XMLHttpRequest etc part of the WebAPIs? They are not "Javascript" in the sense of the word. So JS is single-threaded, the environment itself might be not. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest run on the main thread. This is because it requires 0% CPU time to **wait** for something. It makes zero sense to spawn threads to wait for network requests unless you don't know how to do non-blocking I/O or are lazy. You are wrong. **JAVASCRIPT IS BASICALLY SINGLE THREADED INCLUDING XMLHTTPREQUEST**. In the browser the only thing that is multi-threaded is another tab and web workers. Each tab is a single thread (it used to be all tabs run on the same thread). On node.js the only thing that run on separate threads are file I/O, zip compression, DNS requests and encryption

Answer (score 1):

As per the MDN:-

> The Worker interface spawns real OS-level threads, and mindful programmers may be concerned that concurrency can cause “interesting” effects in your code if you aren't careful.

Reference:- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#about_thread_safety

Answer (score 0):

**The documentation does not define whether the web worker runs in a separate thread or process (or another similar construct).** So, depending on the hardware architecture of the processor on which the program is executed, the Operating System and the implementation of the JavaScript engine used, it may be different.

However, I guess that the essence of this question is: **Can the Operating System use multiple CPU cores by using web workers?** If so, the answer is: **YES!!! Even regardless of the implementation of the JavaScript engine!**

As long as the processor has many cores, and the Operating System can make use of them, **even if the Web Worker's script is executed within another thread of the same process, these threads will be able to run on different cores** because the "process" is a construct of an Operating System and itself can run on several processor cores, just as several processes can run on a single core.

**P.S. If you want the code to be executed 100% in another process, delegate it to another service (e.g. running on a different server).**